# BiFunction - apply method should always return the second argument. Why?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to identify the numbers from a list whose predecessor is greater than its value.

In the lambda expression if I return b, it behaves as expected but if I return a, it gives wrong output.

What is the difference between these two return statements?

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,8,7);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream().reduce((a,b) -> {if (a < b) result.add(a);return b;});
    System.out.println(result);

    result.clear();
    list.stream().reduce((a,b) -> {if (a < b) result.add(a);return a;});
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: Using `reduce()` to change external state (`result`) and then ignoring the resulting is stretching the semantics very far. I wouldn’t recommend it. What you want sounds like a stateful `filter()`.

Comment: What does “predecessor is greater than its value” mean anyway? Your results do not match that description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reduction you are performing - using `Optional<T> java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` - is equivalent to the following pseudo code (taken from the Javadoc):

```
boolean foundAny = false;
T result = null;
for (T element : this stream) {
    if (!foundAny) {
        foundAny = true;
        result = element;
    } else {
        result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
    }
}
return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

As you can see, the intermediate `result` of the reduction is passed as the first argument of the accumulator and the current `element` of the `Stream` is passed as the second argument.

Hence, when your lambda expression returns the second  argument `b` (first snippet), the intermediate result becomes the current element of the `Stream`, which you add to the `List` on the next iteration.

When your lambda returns the first argument `a` (second snippet), the intermediate result remains unchanged (always `1`, the first element of the `Stream`), and you keep adding that value to the `List`.

Let's verify this with the actual numbers:

`result` is initialized to the first element of the Stream `1`.

Then, the first snippet calls `accumulator.apply(1,2)`, adding `1` to the `List` and returning `2` (which becomes the new intermediate result). The next iteration will add `2` to the `List` and return `3`. And so on...

The second snippet calls `accumulator.apply(1,2)`, adding `1` to the `List` and returning 1 (which remains the new intermediate result). The next iteration will add `1` to the `List` again and return `1` again. And so on...

To summarize, your two accumulation functions have a different functionality:

The first results in the last element of the `Stream` (since it keeps discarding the current result and replacing it with the current element).

The second results in the first element of the `Stream` (since it keeps the first element and ignores all other elements).

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but since I said a stateful filter would be better, I felt oblige to show it. Take the follow stateful predicate:

```
public class GreaterThanPreceding implements Predicate<Integer> {
    private Integer preceding = null;

    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer current) {
        boolean greaterThan = preceding == null || (current > preceding);
        preceding = current;
        return greaterThan;
    }
}
```

With that, the stream operation would look like this:

```
List<Integer> collected = list.stream()
        .filter(new GreaterThanPreceding())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collected);
```

Comment: Well, it works. But a `Predicate` that holds state? Yuk!

Comment: You are right. Actually, if you drop the `implements Predicate<>` bit, it does not pretend to be a predicate anymore, but `filter()` will still accept it. A stateful stream filter is a bit questionable in itself.